# How to split two kind of values in the column and count the number of occurrence?

Tags: python, pandas

I want have a dataframe which has a TRUE and FALSE column. I want to get a dataframe like :

**Sample Input**

```
Country | Class | Catalog
A | abc | TRUE  
A | abc | FALSE
B | def | TRUE
C | ghi | FALSE
```

**Sample Output**

```
Country | Class | TRUE | FALSE | TOTAL 
A       |  abc  |    1 | 1     | 2
B       | def   |   1  | 0     | 1
C       | ghi   |   0  | 1     | 1
```

I had tried :

```
df.groupby(['Country','Class','Country'])['Catalog'].value_counts()
```

but I did not get the desired results.

Any help around this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with remove last row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = (pd.crosstab([df['Country'], df['Class']],
                    df['Catalog'],
                    margins=True,
                    margins_name='TOTAL')
         .iloc[:-1])
print (df1)
Catalog        False  True  TOTAL
Country Class                    
A       abc        1     1      2
B       def        0     1      1
C       ghi        1     0      1
```

Your solution should be changed by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and added new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) filled by `sum`s:

```
#removed repeated column in groupby
df1 = (df.groupby(['Country','Class'])['Catalog']
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .assign(Total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
print (df1)
Catalog        False  True  Total
Country Class                    
A       abc        1     1      2
B       def        0     1      1
C       ghi        1     0      1
```

Last for columns from `MultiIndex` add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
  Country Class  False  True  Total
0       A   abc      1     1      2
1       B   def      0     1      1
2       C   ghi      1     0      1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the second solution but the numbers are not matching while verifying it with a pivot table in Excel, Trying to find out why.

Comment: @coder_bg - Hmmm, hard to know, difference is huge?

Comment: Yes, quite significant. Instead of SUM should we use COUNT?

Comment: @coder_bg - Is possible change data for see wrong ouput?

Comment: This is also giving the TOTAL wrong. TRUE 5 FALSE 0 is giving TOTAL 2 but it should be 5.

Comment: @coder_bg - It seems data related problem, is possible share data with wrong ouput? Because question data working perfectly.